# What servers does Samaritan run on?

Tags: person-of-interest

In Person of Interest, the Machine is [shown](http://personofinterest.wikia.com/wiki/The_Machine#) to be running on a on IFT Sabre Blade 2437 servers which are renamed Dell PowerEdge SC1425 servers.
At the end of season 3 we can see server farms with Samaritan's servers. Does anyone know which real life models are shown there?

Comment: I believe that further in the serie you could see new servers are bought (I will not say who they are for).